Setting up chromedriver with Docker image (NodeJS)
I have a problem setting up chromedriver to work with Docker image on raspberry pi 4.
When I run NodeJS script using the terminal (node app.js) it works fine and can use the chromedriver located at: /usr/bin/chromedriver
But after building and running the container it couldn't find the chromedriver.
# Use an official Node.js image as base
FROM node:latest

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy package.json and package-lock.json to the working directory
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install

# Copy the rest of the application code
COPY . .

# Expose the port your app runs on
EXPOSE 3004

# Command to run the application
CMD ["node", "app.js"]

App.js (part of the code)
        const targetURL = "https://google.com";
        const chromeDriverPath = '/home/node/chromedriver';
        serviceBuilder = new ServiceBuilder(chromeDriverPath);

        // Define Chrome options
        const options = new Options();
        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
    
        let driver = await new Builder()
            .forBrowser('chrome')
            .setChromeService(serviceBuilder)
            .setChromeOptions(options)
            .build();

Docker commands:
docker build -t image-name .
docker run -d -p 3004:3004 --name image-name -v /usr/bin/chromedriver:/home/node/chromedriver image-name 

I think that when running app.js using the terminal it can access to /usr/bin/chromedriver but when running inside container it doesn't have access to /usr/bin/chromedriver
Error code I get:
Server listening on port: 3004
/app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:256
              let cancelToken = earlyTermination.catch((e) => reject(Error(e.message)))
                                                                     ^
Error: Server terminated early with status 127
    at /app/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:256:70
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
Node.js v21.7.2

I've tried to search everywhere on the internet but didn't find any solution.
